# Visual Studio 2010 (Visual Basic) MapToIPv4

Tags: vb.net

I have no idea how to use this in visual studio 2010

```
Dim hostIP As IPAddress
hostIP = ipHostInfo.AddressList(CType(logNconfig.Addresslist.ToString(), Integer))
TxtIP.Text = hostIP.MapToIPv4.ToString()
```

MapToIPv4 is not working 2010 because it is not member of system.net.IPAddress..
But these code can be run as well in VS 2013  .. Do you guys have any solution to run this in visual basic 2010?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

MapToIpV4 method is available with the .NET 4.5 framework only, which isn't supported in visual studio 2010. You will have to implement the method yourself as the NET namespace hasn't yet been made open source.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: do you have any suggestion to avoid using MapToIPV4 ? :(